# Calling an array element throws error 'list index out of range'

Tags: python-3.x

When using 2d arrays, I can add these elements, but it won't let me call an element; it throws a 'list index out of range'

```
a = []
for i in range (0,10):
    x = str(input("insert player x"))
    blah.append([x,0])
for i in range(0,10):
    bleh = blah[0,1]
```

Comment: You defined neither ``blah`` nor ``bleh``. This will throw a NameError.

Comment: `blah[0, 1]` will throw `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`, please give a minimal workable code which can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. In the `blah` list that you create, why do you need to append 0 with the input? The `blah` variable is a list of list. For accessing the elements in it, just call the list with `i` as in `blah[i]`.

Refer to the below code:

```
blah = []
for i in range (0,10):
    x = str(i)
    blah.append([x,0])

for i in range(0,10):
    bleh = blah[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right, this code:

```
bleh = []
blah = []
a = []
for i in range (10):
    x = str(input("insert player x"))
    blah.append([x, i])
```

with these inputs:

```
insert player x: input1
insert player x: input2
insert player x: input3
insert player x: input4
insert player x: input5
insert player x: input6
insert player x: input7
insert player x: input8
insert player x: input9
insert player x: input10
```

gives you this output:

```
[[' input1', 0], [' input2', 1], [' input3', 2], [' input4', 3], [' input5', 4], [' input6', 5], [' input7', 6], [' input8', 7], [' input9', 8], [' input10', 9]]
```

I hope that helps.